# Trouble adding multiple objects to list in Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist, addition

I've got a basic investment calculator that I'm writing in Java, and I can't seem to add multiple investment objects to an ArrayList.  Here are some of the basics (problem lines are in the "if adding a 401k" block):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    input = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Investment> invList = new ArrayList();

    int mainChoice = Util.mainMenu();

    while(3 != mainChoice) {

        //Add new investment
        if (1 == mainChoice) {
            int invChoice = Util.invMenu();

            //If adding a 401k
            if (1 == invChoice) {
                //gets info from user, these get passed as arguments when creating new object below

                //RetPlan401k extends the Investment superclass
                RetPlan401k inv = new RetPlan401k(invName, bal401k, contrb401k, ret401k, match, cap);
                invList.add(inv);
            }
            ...
```

I know from debugging that I can add as many Investment objects to the list as I'd like, however when I go to print info on each object (for sake of simplicity, let's say something like:

```
(for int i = 0; i < invList.size(); ++i){
System.out.print("Investment name: " + invList.get(i).getName());
})
```

it prints the name of the most recent object added invList.size() times.  I.e. I've got invList.size() objects, all of which contain the exact same information.

This is like Data Structures 101 here, but I'm having a moment and just not seeing it.  Why isn't each Investment object being printed according to how it was input?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your list ading/printing logic seems in order. Perhaps there is an error in your UI logic. Please consider adding a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: To get more info on the problem, try using a for-each loop to print `for (Investment inv : invList) ...` and also print out `System.identityHashCode()` for each object to see if it is likely the same reference.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved...turns out I had some erroneous 'static' keywords in my object class.  That'll get ya every time.  Thanks all.